# List all records that were inserted during specific time of each day in datetime field

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Would like to write a query that will list only the records, that were inserted between 8.00 PM and 11:59 PM for that day.

Note: The uploaddate field contains both date and time. Thus, the record could be inserted days earlier or later. I'm interested in filtering only records that was inserted on that day between 8.00 PM and 11.59 PM.

The uploadtime is available in the field uploaddate. I'm able to do it for a single day and also able to do it over multiple days using R/Python code.

[image]

In the above example, only the highlighted record should be include and the rest should be excluded.

Query to list for a single day.

```
select * 
from dbo.table
where t = '20220204'
  and uploaddate between '2022-02-04 20:00:00' and '2022-02-04 23:59:00' 
  and uploaddate is not null
order by uploaddate desc
```

R code to list for multiple days

```
thisDate = Sys.Date() 
currentDate = as.Date('2021-01-01', format("%Y-%m-%d"))
allRows = NULL
while ( currentDate < thisDate) {
  if ( format(currentDate, "%u") < 6 ) {
    thisDateStr = as.numeric(format(currentDate,"%Y"))*10000+as.numeric(format(currentDate,"%m"))*100+as.numeric(format(currentDate,"%d"))
    uploadDateStart = paste0(format(currentDate, format = "%Y-%m-%d") , " 20:00:00", sep="")
    uploadDateEnd= paste0(format(currentDate, format = "%Y-%m-%d") , " 23:59:00", sep="")
    query = paste0("select * from dbo.table where t = '", thisDateStr,"' and uploaddate is not null and uploaddate between '", uploadDateStart, "' and '", uploadDateEnd , "' order by uploaddate desc ", sep="")
    rowsToAdd =sqlQuery(dbhandle_prod,daily_market_data_query)
    if ( nrow(daily_market_data_results) > 0 ) {
      allRows = rbind(allRows, rowsToAdd )
    }
  }
  currentDate = currentDate + 1
}
```

Wondering, if it is possible to do it in SQL Server without having to write R/Python code.

Comment: When you did your research into datetime functions available for SQL Server what did you find?

Comment: @DaleK, the field contains both date and time and I want to make sure that I am only looking at the record that was inserted for that day and not earlier or later.

Comment: I understand, and SQL Server has a bunch of datetime functions that will help you solve that problem - have you looked at them?

Comment: How about you give us sample data and expected results?

Comment: Now your question is no longer clear, you say " I'm interested in filtering only records that was inserted on that day" which implies for a single day. However the rest of your question implies you want to consider multiple days... which is it?

Comment: Will look at it. I did not know that I could filter that particular day's time in one query.

Comment: @Charlieface, will do.

Comment: @Charlieface, added a simple table explaining my question in detail.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Your example SQL query already returns the correct results? What do you need help with?

Comment: In T-SQL, you could add `AND CAST(uploaddate AS time) >= '20:00:00` to evaluate only the time portion of the value.

Comment: So what doesn't work about your existing query, it seems to do what you want? Side point: it seems silly to exclude anything between `23:59:00` and midnight, you probably want to do `and uploaddate >= '2022-02-04 20:00:00' and uploaddate < '2022-02-05 00:00:00'`

Comment: @Charlieface, I need to do it for every single day for multi years. Instead, of running a R/Python code , is there a way to write the whole thing in SQL query?

Comment: So why wouldn't you want row 3? And why are you filtering on column `t` if you don't care about it? Sounds like you just need `where cast(uploaddate as time) >= cast('20:00:00' as time)`. You're not answering whether you have tried any of these, they seem to fit what you want

Comment: @DaleK, For more than one day, is it possible to do it in sql server? In other words, is it possible to restrict uploaddate between 8.00 PM and 11.59 PM for that particular date only (t)?

Comment: @Charlieface, it is a business requirement.

Comment: Are you aware that by using `between '2022-02-04 20:00:00' and '2022-02-04 23:59:00'` like that you are ignoring records inserted from `'2022-02-04 23:59:00.003'` through `'2022-02-04 23:59:59.997'`? Are those important to you?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, that change is simple. I'm aware of it. But the bigger question is can I do multiple dates in a single query?

Comment: @nsivakr but your question and sample data only refers to a single day? I've been trying to make this point to you in multiple comments above. Please ensure your question is clear, and that your sample data fully represents the scenario you are interested in.

Comment: @Dale K, the sample data is for one day. But I need to repeat this over multiple days. I've written a R program to achieve the same. Is it possible to achieve multiple days with SQL query? That is my question.

Comment: So provide sample data and desired results that illustrate the multi-day problem if that is what you are trying to solve. Your question is very confusing because you talk mostly about single day, but seems you want to solve multi day. And then check the SQL Server datetime functions for inspiration.

Comment: Agreed, I'm confused about the requirement also. And I don;t understand where the `t` column comes in, it seems to have no bearing. *"It is a business requirement"* What is? To filter column `t`? Or to filter multiple dates, or only that date, what? The whole thing is just confused

Comment: @Charlieface, for each t, if the uploaddate is between 8.00 PM and 11.59.59 PM for that date, then the record should be included.  If the uploaddate is outside of these times for that date, then it should be excluded.

Comment: And as requested please don't use images. We can't copy and paste the data out to assist you.

Comment: @nsivakr rather than continuing to try and explain in the comments, please update your question so that the question is clear, and the sample data and desired results match your expectations (and use formatted text not images).

Comment: And then consider `cast(MyColumn as time)`.

Comment: Why "for each `t`" it sounds like `t` has no bearing on anything, you don't need to filter it at all? Does there have to be a correlation between `t` and `uploaddate`? What happens if `t` is `20220204` but `uploaddate` is `2022-02-05 21:00:00`

Comment: @Charlieface, that is the whole point. We ignore such records. We only need records that were inserted between 8.00 PM and 12.00 midnight for that date (t).

Comment: OK we're getting somewhere finally. So how about `where uploaddate >= dateadd(hour, 20, cast(t as datetime)) and uploaddate < dateadd(day, 1, t)` in other words the `uploaddate` must be between 20 hours after `t` and 1 day after `t`

Comment: @Charlieface, Thanks. Will try now.

Comment: @Charlieface, would you mind posting this as answer. Will accept it. This solves my issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just want to ensure that `uploaddate` is on the same day as `t`, and after `20:00:00`. So you can just check that using date artithmetic

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM dbo.[table] t
WHERE t.uploaddate >= DATEADD(hour, 20, CAST(t as datetime))
  AND t.uploaddate < DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(t as datetime))
ORDER BY
  uploaddate DESC;
```

If `t` is already a `datetime` value you can remove the two casts.